# How to set the order of child directives which are registered on parent directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say I have a form like this:

```
<form>
  <label for="foo-1">Lorem 1</label> ... <input id="foo-1" />
  ...
  <label for="foo-N">Lorem N</label> ... <input id="foo-N" />
</form>
```

For each of these elements I have a directive for some form-related logic. It could look like this.

```
<form x-parent>
  <label for="foo-1" x-child-1>Lorem 1</label> ... <input id="foo-1" x-child-2 />
  ...
  <label for="foo-N" x-child-1>Lorem N</label> ... <input id="foo-N" x-child-2 />
</form>
```

`x-child-1` and `x-child-2` `require: "xParent"` and register themselves on the `xParentCtrl`.

**Question**

Can I specify that every `x-child-2` should register on `xParentCtrl` *before* `x-child-1`? I *cannot* merge `x-child-1` and `x-child-2` into a new directive like `x-super-child` as I don't know which markup surrounds the directives. I also want to use sometimes only `x-child-1` or only `x-child-2`, but if both are present, I need to execute `x-child-2` before `x-child-1`.

Comment: Please clarify: what's your objective in defining the order in which they register: what should happen differently depending on the sequencing that doesn't happen by default? It sounds like what you want is to alter an order of execution for the parent controller's interaction with the children. In which case it sounds like you just want to create your own priority argument that you supply when you register them, so the parent can use that to interact with the children in the correct sequence...

Comment: `x-child-2` should add some data to `xParentCtrl`. If `x-child-1` kicks in it does different things dependent on the data of `x-child-2`. I think @hon2as answer will work. Just need to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exploit the fact that the `link.post` functions (used most often simply as `link`) are first run on the children and only then on the parent. So, you can do something like the this:

```
.directive('childOne', function () {
    return {
        require: ['parent', 'childOne'],
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrls) {
            var parentCtrl = ctrls[0],
                ctrl = ctrls[1];
            parentCtrl.register(ctrl, $element[0]);
        }
    };
})
.directive('childTwo', function () {
    return ...; // same as childOne
})
.directive('parent', function () {
    return {
        require: 'parentCtrl',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, parentCtrl) {
            // do whatever you want with your child controllers
            // in any order you want (they're all registered now,
            // so it's up to you)
        },
        controller: function () {
            this.register = function (childCtrl, element) {
                // store the controller associated with its element,
                // but don't perform any other logic immediately; leave
                // it to this directive's linking function
            };
        }
    };
})
```

---

However, the above works only as long as there's no asynchronous template loading between your parent and child directives (most commonly a result of using `templateUrl`). If that is not the case, you need to re-think your design and either

- place an intermediary "registry" directive collecting the children controllers close enough to the children that there's no asynchronous loading in between, or
- redesign your logic not to require the correct order of registration.

Comment: Is this part intended in `childOne`: `require: ['parent', 'childOne']`? I'll try it and mark your answer as accepted afterwards. Thanks.

Comment: It's very much intended. Child's `link` function needs to get both controllers, `parent`'s and its own, if it is to register the latter with the former.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, so the child can use its own controller.

Regarding the solution: It looks like this works only, if `childOne` and `childTwo` isn't wrapped in another directive :(

Comment: The accepted answer only works if the child directives aren't inside another arbitrary which uses "templateUrl". See http://jsfiddle.net/z2vg6dup/

Comment: Interesting. I'll add that limitation to the answer body. Unfortunately, it seems that whenever you use `templateUrl`, you're [going off the deep end](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8877).